# ASP.NET Core 2.1 HttpClient requesting Google not working on server machine

Tags: dns, asp.net-core-mvc, dotnet-httpclient, iis-8.5

I am very new to Webprogramming, ASP.NET Core and C#, so maybe my question is easy to answer, but i can't find a solution for my problem :-(

I have a working ASP.NET Core 2.1 application and now i am trying to reach an external REST client to get a JSON response. This is working fine on my testing machine, but once i published it on my Windwos 2012 R2 Server with IIS 8.5 as reverse proxy, its not working anymore.

Now i built a TestController to check whats going on:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

    public TestController(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://www.google.at");
            return Content(response.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Content($"{e.Message} -- {e.InnerException} -- {e.StackTrace}");
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

This code works fine on the test machine.
Running this code on production behind IIS i get the follwing response:

> The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found -- System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (11004): The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found
>      at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken) --    at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
>      at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
>      at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask`1 creationTask)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
>      at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
>      at DocudatWebApp.Controllers.TestController.Index() in C:\Users\105026676\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\DocudatWebApp\DocudatWebApp\Controllers\TestController.cs:line 29

The server is running behind a proxy to access external sites. So i tried to set a proxy in web.config, which also did not work:

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled ="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
      <proxy scriptLocation="http://myapps.setpac.ge.com/pac.pac" bypassonlocal="true" />
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" />
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=11" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Now i saw somewhere that this maybe a DNS issue.
I tried to figure this out using nslookup on the server. Not sure if am using this right but this is the result:
[Screenshot cmd.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JdVf.png)

So it seems to me that the server is not able to resolve the name.

Does anyone have a idea?

Comment: Ok, i found something. When i add the proxy script into web.config AND use the httpClient with proxy settings, then i get the correct response on the TestController.

Comment: ASP.NET Core doesn't use web.config, so it's adding the proxy to your `HttpClient` that does the trick.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Thanks for looking into my problem. I need the web.config to set the default proxy for the IIS AND need to set the proxy on the `HttpClient`. Now its working. If i miss one of those two it's not.